# Internet access robust test to several different sites (command line)

Tags: networking, bash, internet

It seems my ISP is a mess, blocking some relevant and renowned sites/IPs (maybe through DNS, I don't really know) and not others, it's been a nightmare.

Is there a command line script to test internet access to a wide (I know, fully is literally impossible) variety of known websites and IP addresses? A kind of `AND` amongst several `ping`s to different credited websites and IPs, such that I can test the "health" of the DNS servers I'm using and the freedom of internet access I'm allowed to.

I simple do not want to do `ping` all the time and it's been like lottery. It seems I can use a bash with `wget --spider --quiet http://example.com`, but has anyone a script or bash ready to use that want to share?

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1104303/how-do-i-change-my-dns-on-ubuntu-18-04-which-dns-should-i-use/1104315#1104315

Comment: @chili555 I know I can edit my DNS, but I really wanted a robust internet access test

Answer (score 1):

If they're just using DNS to block you, just use a custom DNS such as OpenDNS instead of the one your ISP is giving you automatically.  You should even be able to configure your router to use OpenDNS instead of your ISP's DNS so that all devices on your network will route through OpenDNS without having to manually configure each device.

Comment: I know I can edit my DNS, but I really wanted a robust internet access test